# Regular expression to match string after exactly two forward slash

Tags: python, regex

say I have a file name like this

```
 ./Music/pop-rock/Stray Cats/Greatest Hits/01 - Rock This Town.ogg
 ./Music/classical/Handel/Basic Handel/disk1/04 - Wassermusik - Allegro.ogg
```

I want a regular expression that will match

```
Stray Cats
```

and

```
Handel
```

since they come after exactly two forward slash.

Also will I use the idea if I wanted to match what came exactly after 3 forward slashes?

like

```
Greatest Hits
```

I have searched and haven't got any expression that is consistent all through

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Also, there are no backslashes anywhere in your question.

Comment: You might be happier with simple `.split('/')` or even with using pathlib.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I edited. I meant forward slash

Comment: I'd argue that getting a single value out of a **list** is less complex than even a trivial regular expression.

Comment: @KlausD. True. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't use regex. Maybe use str.split() like so:

```
filepath = './Music/pop-rock/Stray Cats/Greatest Hits/01 - Rock This Town.ogg'
answer = filepath.split('/')[3]
```

If you want to get the result after 3 slashes, just change the index of the split list.

Comment: Sorry, I am pretty new to SO and didn't know how it works. I accepted your answer

Answer (score 1):

Instead of regex, use a str.split() function.  Do something like:

```
pathname = r'./Music/classical/Handel/Basic Handel/disk1/04 - Wassermusik - Allegro.ogg'
my_str = pathname.split('/')[3]
```